# Cubism callback array seemingly replaced

Tags: callback, d3.js, cubism.js

I'm using some static data to generate charts using cubism's *context.metric* function. However, all of the charts end up displaying the same array of values (the last one passed in) although I passed in different arrays in the *callback* function.

```
var metrics = [];
for (var key in toGraph) {
    var m = context.metric(function(start, stop, step, callback) {
        callback(null, toGraph[key]);
    }, key);

    metrics.push(m);
}
```

*toGraph* is a dictionary with key being the name of each metric and the value being an array of the metric values.

The values ended up being displayed are always the last array of values I pass in.

I couldn't figure out what's wrong. Am I using *context.metric* wrong or using the callback function wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a javascript closure inside loop problem.

Examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) and [this](http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62) explained the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this example - http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/5803524